# How to change MUI Accordion title font size

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I wanted to change the MUI-5 Accordion title font size. I think I have to override it. but I don't know how to override CSS in MUI-5. it also doesn't have 'SX', it has 'htmlSx'.  I tried to use it. but it didn't work.

```
const AccordionNew: FC<AccordionProps> = ({ header, children }) => {
    return (
        <Box>
            <Accordion
                defaultExpanded={false}
                title={header}
                detailsContent={children}
                 htmlSx={(theme: Theme) => ({
                       '& .MuiTypography-h5': {
                         fontSize: '9px',
                        }
                     }),
                 }
            />
        </Box>
    );
};
```

I tried to override the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sx` prop of the `Accordion` and select class of the header and change its style:

```
export default function SimpleAccordion() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Accordion 
        sx={{'& .MuiTypography-root' :{   //use sx and select related class
              fontSize:'20px'             // change its style
      }}}>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel1a-content"
          id="panel1a-header"
        >
          <Typography>Accordion 1</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
            malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit wonderful-torvalds-hgog9d]

Answer (score 0):

it has a class name MuiAccordion-root that you can access it from css

sth like this :

```
.MuiAccordion-root .MuiAccordionSummary-content p{
   font-size:9px
}
```

Comment: Where exactly I should add these styles?

Comment: your css file that you import in your app
sth like styles.css

Comment: can I do this without importing a css file?  only using external css

Comment: you can use themeProvider and makeStyle.
wanna use one of these ?

Comment: sx={{
                    '& .MuiAccordion-root .MuiAccordionSummary-content p': {
                        fontSize: '9px',
                    },
                }}

Comment: i used it like this. still didn't work

Comment: you can use makeStyle to handle this https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/